# SQL Database design auto populating table data with another table

Tags: mysql

Creating the database

```
CREATE DATABASE nicholasShaffer;
```

Creating table customer for members to sign up and have data stored as a primary field

```
CREATE TABLE Customers ( 
MemberID int NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT, 
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
City varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
Address varchar(255), 
Zip int NOT NULL, 
CellNumber int NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY MemberID
)
```

Creating Table DeviceID to be the child table to customers

```
CREATE TABLE DeviceID ( 
ID int, 
CellNumber int NOT NULL, 
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (LastName, CellNumber)
)
```

This is where I am having the issue, The table DeviceID.CellNumber should auto populate from Customers.CellNumber but something seems to be wrong with my join statement, What am i missing from this statement to have deviceID.cellnumber populate with what ever is already entered into customers.CellNumber>

```
SELECT deviceid.CellNumber, customers.CellNumber
FROM deviceid
LEFT JOIN customers ON deviceid.CellNumber = customers.CellNumber;
```

Comment: You go and create that amazing member id column, and then relate devices to lastnames. Shall we have a little think about how weird that might be?

Comment: should i relate it to MemberID rather than lastname? I wanted MemberID to be a unique key for the customers that is auto generated and can be used as a sole means to find any customer. The cellnumber lastname relation was supposed to be means of generating the memberID, did i do that wrong?

Comment: I feel like you've answered your own question

Comment: There's another problem here, in that you have `CellNumber` in the Customer table too.  Is `CellNumber` a property of the customer or of the device?  My gut tells me it's probably the latter (in which case it shouldn't be in the former table) but perhaps I have it wrong?  What is the cardinality of this relation?  Presumably one customer might have many devices (and many cell numbers)?

Comment: Also, you are trying to make `(CellNumber, LastName)` your primary key in `Customers` yet `MemberID` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  This won't work—the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column *must* be the primary key.  Moreover, `(CellNumber, LastName)` is a bizarre choice of primary key: it permits the same `CellNumber` to appear in multiple customers each having different values for `LastName`.  However, as commented above, `CellNumber` probably shouldn't appear in this table at all...

Comment: I have edited the code to the above, is this any bit closer to getting the functionality I desire? Im sorry im very new in database design and this project is quite challenging. 
I am looking to have an app that monitors air quality within a home. Customers sign up with an app and upon sign up A memberID is generated automatically to assign each customer with a unique ID to use for monitoring their services. The DeviceID table should then obtain the memberID store it in the DeviceID.ID row and assign the lastname and cellnumber from Customers table to the corresponding rows in DeviceID.

Comment: The reason for having cell number in both tables is because this info MUST MUST MUST match in both tables to ensure that each customers data that will soon be added to the table DeviceID such as air quality, carbon detection, air filter change date, is belonging to the customer. I hope that makes sense

Comment: A select statement of itself will not populate deviceid from Customers. The select needs to be part of an insert or possibly update statement and you may need a trigger.

Comment: Don't duplicate `CellNumber` across both tables—that violates the [principle of orthogonal design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_orthogonal_design).  Keep it in the table to which the attribute belongs (customer or device?) and then retrieve it as required by *joining* the tables using the appropriate relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to be able to represent a single customer having multiple devices, each with its own cell number.

This being the case, `CellNumber` is a property of the device and not the customer—and therefore it should appear in the former's table but not the latter's.

Since a device belongs to a single customer, the tables can be related using a "foreign key" (of the customer) in the devices table.  The best key to use is the primary key of the related table.

What should the primary key of the customer table be?  You have attempted to specify a "composite primary key" over the two columns `(CellNumber, LastName)`.  However, we have not only already decided to remove `CellNumber` from this table but you also were trying to have `MemberID` auto-incremented (which is a good thing), and auto-incremented columns in MySQL *must* be the table's primary key.

Remember, the purpose of a key is to uniquely identify a record; and the *primary key* should be the key that is primarily used for identifying records.  `MemberID` does indeed appear to be the most appropriate primary key here.

Therefore we have:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers ( 
  MemberID  SERIAL, -- SERIAL is a handy shorthand for
                    -- BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  LastName  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  City      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Address   VARCHAR(255),
  Zip       INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Devices ( 
  DeviceID   SERIAL,
  MemberID   BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CellNumber INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES Customers (MemberID)
    -- This foreign key constraint will enforce the requirement that a record
    -- with the given MemberID exists in the Customers table
);
```

Then to query the joined combination:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers JOIN Devices USING (MemberID)
```

This query will return a record for each related customer-device combination.  Therefore, if a customer has multiple devices, there will be multiple records for that customer in the resultset.  Usually this is exactly what you want, and your application can handle the duplicates according to its needs, but for brevity you may wish to *group* the results so as to have only one record per customer—eg:

```
SELECT   Customers.*, GROUP_CONCAT(Devices.CellNumber)
FROM     Customers JOIN Devices USING (MemberID)
GROUP BY MemberID
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking to do! Ok, so just asking for some food for thought, comparing your code to my code its clear to me that my structure/grouping/organization needs some work. Im a student and SQL is very new to me, Ive been exposed to the syntax and the general use of it. But I feel very lost as far as "tying the knots together" or the relations / use between the keys (or relations?). Do you have any suggestions? or references? or words of wisdom concerning Keys and relations?

Comment: I just did a quick search for "introduction to relational database design" and came across [A Quick-Start Tutorial on Relational Database Design](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html), which I have very briefly scanned over and it appears to be a fairly accessible introduction to the fundamentals?

Comment: It's UNIQUE, not PRIMARY.